# which is faster GPRS vs 4G on arduino?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, gprs

I am using Sim800 GPRS to send data to MySQL server online.
I use Arduino mega 2560

for one update in MySQL, it takes 1-2 seconds to run required AT commands

If I use a 4G module like SIM7000E will this be faster ? will update time reduce?

or

if I use eps32 wifi will this be faster?

in other words which module will give me fast execution and come back to the main loop? sim800 or sim7000e or esp32

Comment: No, both have more then sufficient bandwidth for your information... The delay is just network latency over cellular and making the initial connection.

Comment: @MadHatter  is there a way to speed up the process? I need to get rid off hanging the loop for 1-2 seconds while data is uploading

Comment: Don't block your software while transmitting? Unless are you using someone else's library? Maybe rewrite it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your delay is related to data transfer speed(relatively if you transfer packages bigger than 200 kb), of course SIM7000E will be faster.

As you can see below pictures, LTE has approximately 4 times faster than GPRS 
[image: GPRS]
[image: LTE]

You can find more information to compare from these links :
[SIM800](https://simcom.ee/modules/gsm-gprs/sim800/)
[SIM7000E](https://simcom.ee/modules/iot/sim7000e/)